Is there a forumla to estimate the rate of evaporation rate in grams per hour given the speed of wind passing over the surface?
I am doing an experiment, where I investigate the effects of different wind speeds (1,2,3,4,5 $ms^{-1}$) on the evaporation rate of distilled water. I am trying to calculate the theoretical evaporation rate for 100 ml of distilled water in grams per hour. There is a wind blower blowing horizontally over the container of water. The experiment is indoor with a room temperature of 15 deg C, but I do not have any tools to measure the Humidity. Can anyone help?

You need to give more information. What have you already considered? Why did you consider that? What other resources (Google, other Physics SE posts, textbooks, etc.) have you used to find a solution?

You might look at this video from Practical Engineering. Do Droughts Make Floods Worse?. It goes over the hydrology of water infiltration into soil. There are models for this. It is one part of hydrology. You might look to see if there are related models for evaporation. This is important for reservoirs, so I expect there are models.

Measuring humidity can be done with two thermomenters. See Wet-bulb temperature
